# Official xkcd of CodeReview

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I noticed some CS websites have an xkcd that fits what they do pretty well.

I was randomly clicking through some the other day, and I happened upon this:

http://xkcd.com/1513/

PLEASE note that I know that most users here are very kind and helpful with their comments and criticisms. I just think that that particular xkcd fits this SE website very nicely. :D

What do you guys think? I think it would be hilarious to bury it in some part of the website (maybe the "question not found" page) as a joke, see who finds it.

Comment: Does any of those CS websites have the XKCD in their help center or as another part of their main site?

Answer (score 14):

I don't mind injecting a bit of humour into the site to make a point, but that one conveys the opposite of the spirit of Code Review.

Code Review answers should not disparage code without being constructive.  An answer like that "review" would certainly get downvoted and would also merit moderator action as a violation of the [Be Nice Policy](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/148099):

> 1. **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. *If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.*

And if the code really were that bad, a style guide wouldn't be helpful at all.  For that matter, good answers should go way beyond the style guide and provide real insight.  The last thing we want to do is give the impression that this site is about militant enforcement of style guides.

There are some xkcd comics that I like a lot, but this one really falls flat.

Comment: right...i didn't think of it like that. you're absolutely correct, everyone is really nice here. :D i still love that comic though, i think its hilarious.  thanks for your input!

Answer (score 6):

## No.

The Help Center, and 404 Not Found pages and all other pages are supposed to be serious.

This is something that can float around every once in a while in chat as a meme. Truth is, [it has been posted in chat a few times already](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fxkcd.com%2F1513%2F&user=&room=8595).

Comment: LOL i agree very much :D i still think it would be funny though, like if a question can't be found or something, to have that pop up.

Comment: @JosephFarah Same thing applies for question can't be found pages as well.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for taking a look at this :D i just hope the meta post at least gives someone a good laugh XD

Comment: I disagree that page should be/are "serious". If you try to access to http://test.stackexchange.com/ you'll see a picture of panda (which is not "serious"). If I remember correctly, when Stack Overflow is down for whatever reason, there are pictures of the devs doing some funky stuff (like coding on toy computer). There is a part of humor, but I don't think the xkcd  would be a good addition.